# inline-block overflowing on the height of its container?

Tags: html, css

I had this color-container:

```
<div class="color-container">
   <div class="inline" id="red"></div>
   <div class="inline" id="green"></div>
   <div class="inline" id="yellow"> </div>
   <div class="inline" id="blue"> </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.color-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 320px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
 }
```

But my children are overflowing the height of the parent color-container? the children have same style like this:

```
#green {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
  border: solid #333333;
  border-width: 2px 2px 1px 1px;
}
```

The class `inline` is as below:

```
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I was expecting it not to overflow, but this is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should minimize the width and height according to the border as the border is `3px` in total (both horizontally and vertically). and `float:left;`

```css
.color-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 320px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
 }
.color-container > div {
  float:left;
  height: 147px;
  width: 147px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
  border: solid #333333;
  border-width: 2px 2px 1px 1px;
}
#red {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100% 0 0 0;
}
#green {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 0 100% 0 0;
}
#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
}
#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 0 0 100% 0;
}
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-container">
   <div class="inline" id="red"></div>
   <div class="inline" id="green"></div>
   <div class="inline" id="yellow"> </div>
   <div class="inline" id="blue"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the spot! I missed that, I thought there was enough room @300 since child are 150s,